# How to converte EPOCH time into time and date on Arduino?

Tags: time, convert

I have a question on how to convert EPOCH timestamps, which I receive as char*, into `DD.MM.YYYY` and `HH:MM:SS` format separately?

Here is more information on my Arduino project: The Arduino is receiving through an ESP8266 module three different EPOCH timestamps from the OpenWeatherMap API for sunrise, sunset and the current date. I want these 3 pieces of information to be displayed on a 1,3" OLED display, the date in `DD.MM.YYYY` and the other two timestamps in `HH:MM` format.

I was looking in several time libraries like TimeLib and RTC for a solution, but I wasn't able to find one.

That's my code fragment on receiving the timestamps:

```
DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer(4096);
JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(client);

const char* date = root["dt"];
const char* sunrise = root["sys"]["sunrise"];
const char* sunset = root["sys"]["sunset"];
```

How to convert those timestamps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Epoch are seconds from 1970-01-01. Get it from JSON as unsigned long. They are a number in the returned JSON (no `"`)

from https://openweathermap.org/ doc:

`"sys":{"country":"JP","sunrise":1369769524,"sunset":1369821049},`

---

to convert it to string with TimeLib.h:

```
#include <TimeLib.h>
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);

  const char* json = "{\"country\":\"JP\",\"sunrise\":1369769524,\"sunset\":1369821049}";

  DynamicJsonBuffer jsonBuffer;
  JsonObject& root = jsonBuffer.parseObject(json);

  unsigned long t = root["sunrise"];

  char buff[32];
  sprintf(buff, "%02d.%02d.%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", day(t), month(t), year(t), hour(t), minute(t), second(t));

  Serial.println(buff);
}

void loop() {
}
```

Comment: note you might need to divide the timestamp by 1000 if it includes ms, like JS's Dates for example.

Comment: @dandavis, I took the sample JSON from the openweathermap site

Comment: For sure, I'm just pointing out that there's two "epoc"s to be aware of from web services, in general.

Comment: For this example, it's not necessary to divide by 1000. Thank you very much for the help :)

Comment: @Juraj I have one more question to this topic: Can TimeLib also convert EPOCH timestamps to day names?(Monday, etc.)

Comment: dayStr(weekday(t)); or dayShortStr http://playground.arduino.cc/code/time

Answer (score 0):

I'm was having a similar challenge with my custom Wifi library `m_wifi..cpp` for the ESP32 ( [see here](https://github.com/aeonSolutions/aeonlabs-ESP32-C-Base-Firmware-Libraries#readme) )

After reading and googling I ended up coding the solution below:

```
ESP32Time rtc(0);
long int epochTime;
...

rtc.setTime( epochTime  );
Serial.println( rtc.getDateTime(true) );
```

Comment: can it be used on a non esp32 Arduino as in the question?

Comment: yes. you can replicate the code to use on other than ESP32. Just need to find the compatible library for your specific MCU.